# $W^-$ behavior in Neutron decay

Tags: conservation-laws, standard-model, neutrons, weak-interaction, bosons

Why does $W^-$ always decay into electron and anti-neutrino in neutron decay? Why doesn't the $W^-$ particle decay into quark-antiquark pair?

Comment: Why do you think that the W cannot decay to a quark/antiquark pair!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you are asking why the neutron decay like this can happen

[image]
<sub>(image from [W and Z bosons - Weak nuclear force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W_and_Z_bosons#Weak_nuclear_force))</sub>

but a neutron decay creating a $\pi^-$ meson
(which is a $d\bar u$ quark-antiquark pair) doesn't happen.

[image]

According to the conservation laws for electric charge
($Q$), baryon number ($B$) and lepton number ($L$)
both processes would be allowed.

The reason the second process is not allowed, is energy
conservation. To see this consider the masses of the
incoming and outgoing particles.
The mass difference between [neutron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutron) ($939.6\text{ MeV}/c^2$) and
[proton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proton) ($938.3 \text{ MeV}/c^2$) is only $1.3\text{ MeV}/c^2$.
This is not enough to create a [pion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pion) $\pi^-$
which has a mass of $139.6\text{ MeV}/c^2$.

Comment: Thanks a lot...!